# How to get facebook user's public data using facebook id

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know it may sound stupid but i've been googling for a good answer. I want to get a users(not the currently logged in) name with only knowing his/her facebook id. I was only able to access my own public data like photos with access token. How can i get any user's public data with his/her id only? or at least a graph api url that i can use to do the task. This is using facebook sdk on ios. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you're using a mixture of global and app-scoped user ids.

Global ids were generated with a v1.0 app. You can access those global ids without an Access Token, but only until April 30th 2015. The app-scoped user ids were generated with an >=v2.0 app, and always need at least an App Access Token to be able to access the `public_profile` fields.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-public_profile
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: So what do you think? Having that token [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}]; will not work? Did you test it? Or Facebook has introduced a new graph API call to do that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. I doesn't have something to do with iOS SDK stuff...

Comment: is there any workaround?like a url where i just have to pass the facebook id?I'm sorry, but i'm really noob at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think a graph API url should be as simple as:
http://graph.facebook.com/100004242424242
Where number is a facebook id.

Comment: doesn't work on some account ids.
`error: {
message: "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
type: "GraphMethodException",
code: 100
}`

Comment: I think it is becauase users with theese facebook id's does not exist

Comment: i verified the account ids i used. they all exist. i even used my own facebook id.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so by using this graph API function available in Facebook iOS SDK.

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            if (!error && result)
            {
                NSArray* fetchedFriendData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[result objectForKey:@"data"]];
                // User has atleast one frined who has installed this app
                if (fetchedFriendData.count > 0) {


                    for (int i = 0 ; i < fetchedFriendData.count; i++) {
                        NSDictionary *friendInfoDic = [fetchedFriendData objectAtIndex:i];

                        NSLog(@"Friend Count %d info = %@", i + 1, friendInfoDic);
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }];
```

Comment: will this still work even if that account is not a friend of currently logged in account?

Comment: No, you will only receive the basic information of your Facebook friends only. If you have Facebook account id then just call the url as specified by @Mikhail Seryukov.